# Can't get Custom Attribute Value in MVC3 HTML Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, custom-attributes

I've extended the HTML helper with a method that needs an attribute value from the property of the model.  So I've defined a custom attribute as such.

```
    public class ChangeLogFieldAttribute : Attribute {
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
    }
```

It's used like this in my model.

```
    [Display(Name = "Style")]
    [ChangeLogField(FieldName = "styleid")]
    public string Style { get; set; }
```

In my helper method, I've got the following code to get the FieldName value of my attribute, if the attribute is used for the property.

```
        var itemName = ((MemberExpression)ex.Body).Member.Name;

        var containerType = html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType;
        var attribute = ((ChangeLogFieldAttribute[])containerType.GetProperty(html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ChangeLogFieldAttribute), false)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (attribute != null) {
            itemName = attribute.FieldName;
        }
```

However, when I reach this code, I get an exception because the containerType is null.

I'm not sure if I'm doing any of this correct, but I pulled from about 4 different sources to get this far.  If you could suggest a fix to my problem or an alternative, I'd be grateful.

Thanks.

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**

I used Darin Dimitrov's solution, although I had to tweak it some. Here is what I added. I had to check for the existence of the attribute metatdata and all was good.

```
        var fieldName = ((MemberExpression)ex.Body).Member.Name;

        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(ex, html.ViewData);
        if (metadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("fieldName")) { 
            fieldName = (string)metadata.AdditionalValues["fieldName"];
        }
```

Comment: To get a property name, you can use `metadata.PropertyName` instead of `((MemberExpression)ex.Body).Member.Name`.  This doesn't work for field names, though, and I don't see any `.FieldName` or `.MemberName`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could make the attribute metadata aware:

```
public class ChangeLogFieldAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AdditionalValues["fieldName"] = FieldName;
    }
}
```

and then inside the helper:

```
var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(ex, htmlHelper.ViewData);
var fieldName = metadata.AdditionalValues["fieldName"];
```